# Почему L уменьшается?

Tags: c++

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject * Sender)
{
    int l = 0;
    l = 0;

    clock_t t0 = clock();

    while ((clock() - t0) < 1000) {
        BitBlt(GetDC(Panel1->Handle), 0, 0, w, h, hdc2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        l = l + 1;
    }

    Form1->Caption = l;
}
```

Почему L на первом нажатии равен ~1650, а при последующих нажатиях уменьшается. Сначала показывает 750, потом 300 и т.д.

Comment: "Form1->Caption=l;" Caption это string, а l это int... Вопрос: как вы узнаёте что L=1650?

Comment: по капшону =)

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, ну почему? если я ставлю l=222 перед Form1->Caption=l; то в капшоне 222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь сказать глупость, но, по-моему, следует каждый раз явно освобождать контекст устройства. Т.е. цикл while должен выглядеть иначе.

Comment: Соглашусь с @BuilderC. Думаю, нужно вызов GetDC() вынести перед циклом, а после цикла добавить ReleaseDC().

Answer (score 3):

У вас L дважды инициализируется нулем. Затем в цикле увеличивается на 1 при каждой итерации.

Следовательно L равняется количеству циклов while().

Если объясните что делает ваш while, можно будет ответить почему L уменьшается.

Comment: Этот вайл замеряет сколько раз секунду может выполниться bitblt

Comment: >Этот вайл замеряет сколько раз секунду может выполниться bitblt

А заодно этот вайл меряет еще `GetDC` и непосредственно, сам `clock`. Утечка ресурсов страшенная. При этом как-то даже не особо хочется предполагать, в чем проблема, кроме уже освещенных.